# form th:action not working using thymeleaf and spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i am new in spring and thymeleaf, i am trying to submit a form, insert to database, but whe i am using form submission with submission it simply redirects to page and don't invoke to controller
i don't know why,
please, help
here is my Controller

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryServiceImpl categoryService;

    @GetMapping("/adminPage")
    public String index(){
        return "adminPage";
    }
    @GetMapping("/categoryList")
    public String showCategory(){
        return "categoryList";
    }

    @GetMapping("form")
    public String categoryForm(Model model, Category category){
        model.addAttribute("category", category);
       // model.addAttribute("add", true);
//        categoryService.create(category);

        return "admin/categoryForm";
    }
    @PostMapping("create")
    public String addOrgCategory(@Valid Category orgCategory) {
        categoryService.create(orgCategory);
        return "redirect:/categoryList";
    }
```

my html form is here

```
   <form action="#" th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${category}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="text-dark font-bold">Category name</label>
                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" th:value="${category} ? ${category.name} : ' '" th:field="*{name}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            </div>

            <button
                    type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Create
            </button>
        </form>
```

Comment: `@PostMapping("create")` isn't the same as `@{/create}`. You need a leading `/` in your url mapping.

Comment: remove the extra   **action="#"** and simply try - <form th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${category}" method="POST"> . Also, are you having any errors on your console ?

Comment: still forbidden and redirects to /create link

Comment: Can you be please more specific about which controller you're trying to hit (from the sample code, it seems that you're trying to hit **create** controller), which page it redirects to and provided the error stack so that we get to know about the error in detail.

Comment: No, it redirects to /create page and i see blank page with "Forbidden message".

Comment: I solved my problems, it redirects to forbidden page due to spring security, I forgot to give a  current page access  in  the method permitAll() Thanks for replying, your advice also helps me

Answer (score 0):

i know this 3 years late, but I took the / away from the `(th:action="@{/create}")`
so now it looks like this `(th:action="@{create}")` and it works